# Mask clouds in an ImageCollection google earth engine

Tags: landsat, ndvi, google-earth-engine

Is It possible to create .median() Surface Refletance image (landSat 8 RS) without clouds before calculating the NDVI in goolge earth engine? I need to work with a year (eg. 2016-01-01, 2016-12-31), so I need to remove the clouds to create a single image free of clouds and then calculate the NDVI.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer of [Mask clouds in LandSat 8 surface refletance image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241822/mask-clouds-in-landsat-8-surface-refletance-image), one possibility is:

**NOTE**: replace YOUR_PLACE with a *Geometry* or *Feature*

```
// Filter the collection
var col = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC8_SR")
          .filterDate("2016-01-01", "2016-12-31")
          .filterBounds(YOUR_PLACE)

// Mask clouds
var col_noclouds = col.map(function(img) {
                   var mask = img.select(['cfmask']).neq(4)
                   return img.updateMask(mask)
                   })

// Median image
var median = ee.Image(col_noclouds.median())

// NDVI
var median_ndvi = median.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B5'])
```