# Cloud mask for Landsat8 on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series

I'm creating a composite image, in order to create a timeseries. I've already created the composited image, but i am having difficulty masking the clouds of the composite image. I've followed the code from a page having similar problems, however when I run the code (after replacing all the l8_mayo to composite as that is the name of my composite var), I get the error code of composite.map not a function. This error does not come up when I run the exact same code from the previous answer.

Can someone explain how to overcome this problem?

Here is the page I used: [Apply a cloud mask to a Landsat8 collection in Google Earth Engine - time series](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274612/apply-a-cloud-mask-to-a-landsat8-collection-in-google-earth-engine-time-series)

here is my code and the link to my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/e42eaf1819e63e1d679e5db3f4c54e89

(point is the long, lat for Lake Manyara, Tanzania)

```js
//load images for composite
var sr14= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filterBounds(point)
.filterDate('2014-01-01','2014-03-01')
.select(['B4','B3','B2']);

// Temporally composite the images with a maximum value function.
var composite = sr14.max();
Map.setCenter(35.8244, -3.5799);
Map.addLayer(composite, {}, 'max value composite');

var getQABits = function(image, start, end, newName) {
// Compute the bits we need to extract.
var pattern = 0;
for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
   pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
}
// Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
// a new name.
return image.select([0], [newName])
              .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
              .rightShift(start);
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var cloud_shadows = function(image) {
// Select the QA band.
var QA = image.select(['BQA']);
// Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
return getQABits(QA, 7,8, 'Cloud_shadows').eq(1);
// Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var clouds = function(image) {
// Select the QA band.
var QA = image.select(['BQA']);
// Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
return getQABits(QA, 4,4, 'Cloud').eq(0);
// Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

var maskClouds = function(image) {
var cs = cloud_shadows(image);
var c = clouds(image);
image = image.updateMask(cs);
return image.updateMask(c);
};

var composite_free = composite.map(maskClouds);

Map.addLayer(composite_free, 'composite collection without clouds');
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please, read the related answer.

### Use the right parameters and always check metadata

You're trying to filter with `BQA` band and in SR product, there is no `BQA` band, there is `pixel_qa` band instead. Also, bits used are different (3 and 5). Finally, if you are trying to create a cloud-free composite, first sort by cloud cover.

```js
var point = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Point([35.83946228027344, -3.5380934964711126]);

//load images for composite
var sr14= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filterBounds(point)
.filterDate('2014-01-01','2014-03-01').sort('CLOUD_COVER',false);

// Temporally composite the images with a maximum value function.
var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0,max: 1000};
Map.setCenter(35.8244, -3.5799);
Map.addLayer(sr14, visParams, 'max value composite');

var getQABits = function(image, start, end, newName) {
    // Compute the bits we need to extract.
    var pattern = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
    // a new name.
    return image.select([0], [newName])
                  .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
                  .rightShift(start);
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var cloud_shadows = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 3,3, 'cloud_shadows').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var clouds = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 5,5, 'Cloud').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var cs = cloud_shadows(image);
  var c = clouds(image);
  image = image.updateMask(cs);
  return image.updateMask(c);
};

var composite_free = sr14.map(maskClouds);

Map.addLayer(composite_free,visParams, 'composite collection without clouds');
```

Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6a9d2bce417076d1f1b677e775584690

Answer (score 12):

[@Aldo's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277141/115) is the correct one, no doubt, but if you want to make the code shorter and you don't mind loosing the 'core' of cloud masking, you can use a module:

```js
var point = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Point([35.83946228027344, -3.5380934964711126]);

//load images for composite
var sr14= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filterBounds(point)
.filterDate('2014-01-01','2014-03-01')
//.select(['B4','B3','B2']); // if you select those bands you loose BQA band

// Temporally composite the images with a maximum value function.
var composite = sr14.max();
Map.setCenter(35.8244, -3.5799);
var vis = {bands:['B5','B6','B4'],min:0, max:5000}

Map.addLayer(composite, vis, 'max value composite');

var mask = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks')

print(mask.help['landsatSR'])

var mask_function = mask.landsatSR() // mask function

var col_free = sr14.map(mask_function) // apply function to collection
var composite_free = col_free.median() // create composite using max

Map.addLayer(composite_free, vis, 'composite collection without clouds');
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/31b5b21913eefdc05563dfec72c4ee08

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for Collection 2 which is now the recommended collection in GEE. I think it's because the band names are different. Is there any fix? Thank you!

Comment: Also, I wonder why use max() for the composites? Is it better in some way than median() or mean()? Thank you!

Comment: ok, now there are two comments to answer. 1st, yes, C2 is recommended and not implemented yet. 2nd, no reason, but I understand that the most common composite is median, so I'll modify it, thanks