# Downloading all images in an ImageCollection to my local computer from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, image, batch, download

Based on [Filter Sentinel-3 data based on cloud cover over a region of interest](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429418), I managed to get an ImageColection containing the name of hundreds of Sentinel-3 images with specific cloud cover over a region of interest.   Now I wish to ask about downloading this dataset as I need to process them in my local computer.

I see that GEE provides three options for downloading/exporting images:
GoogleDrive: which I don't think has enough space for my application
Google Cloud Space: which I think is not free
GEE asset: which is vague to me how it works and if it is enough for my application or not.

How do I download all images in an ImageCollection to my local computer?

Can I do that with GE asset?

If yes, how?

if no, is there any other way to batch download the images in an ImageCollection from LPDAAC or Scihub Copernicus or these kind of source websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I download all images in an ImageCollection to my local computer?

Earth Engine does not currently offer a prebuilt bulk direct download option. However, you could write a Python or JavaScript program that requests a series of [download URLs using `ee.Image.getDownloadURL`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl). These requests have more limitations on time and size than batch tasks (`Export.*`) but can transfer data direct from EE to your computer without a stop at any cloud storage service.

> Can I do that with GE asset?

No, because that would be just creating another asset in Earth Engine's own storage just like the one you started with.

> if no, is there any other way to batch download the images in an ImageCollection from LPDAAC or Scihub Copernicus or these kind of source websites?

Perhaps. Earth Engine's assets generally have image IDs from the original data provider, which you can use to match up images within EE to those from the provider's site, but every provider is a little different and it'll depend entirely on them whether it would be easy to download a list of IDs.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Based on what you said, I think the best option for me is to go ahead and search/download the images in ImageCollection from the main providers. Interesting is that the ID of images in GEE seems to be slightly different than the ID of the same images in provider sources. Eg. an image with ID: "S3A_OL_1_EFR____20160501T173412_20160501T173712_**20180131T214613**_0179_003_326_2160_LR2_R_NT_002" in GEE cannot be found in Scihub dataset where the ID of the same image is "S3A_OL_1_EFR____20160501T173412_20160501T173712_**20180207T112630**_0179_003_326_2160_LR2_R_NT_002".