# Removing clouds in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have the following code:

```
var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5) ;
qa.BitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).Eq(0).And(qa.BitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).Eq(0));
```

Can anyone explain the methods to me?

Answer (score 0):

There is a long post here that explains some of the details: 
[Cloud mask for Landsat8 on Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277059/cloud-mask-for-landsat8-on-google-earth-engine/277151)

If you still have questions; it helps to ask specific ones. Else you are refered to the forum of earth engine for details: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers