# Creating mean image from cloud free images over ROI in GEE for the Landsat SR products

Tags: google-earth-engine, cloudmasking

I want to filter all the available cloud-free images of the Landsat series of each year separately and find the mean image in Google Earth Engine.  As my ROI is very small, I want images that don't have a cloud over my ROI, not on the entire image.

I am using **Landsat Collection 2 products** that have **surface reflectance** values. Also, as I'm doing temporal analysis, the Landsat 5, 7, and 8 images are included in this.

I'm doing as bellow in GEE for the Landsat 8,

```
Map.centerObject(mumbai, 10); 

//load images for composite
var sr = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 148)).filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 47))
  .filterDate('2013-01-01','2013-12-31')
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER',false);

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}
sr =sr.map(applyScaleFactors);

// Temporally composite the images with a maximum value function.
var visParams = {bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'], min:0 ,max: 0.3};
Map.addLayer(sr, visParams, 'max value composite');

var getQABits = function(image, start, end, newName) {
    // Compute the bits we need to extract.
    var pattern = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
    // a new name.
    return image.select([0], [newName])
                  .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
                  .rightShift(start);
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var cloud_shadows = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['QA_PIXEL']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 3,3, 'cloud_shadows').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var clouds = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['QA_PIXEL']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 5,5, 'Cloud').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var cs = cloud_shadows(image);
  var c = clouds(image);
  image = image.updateMask(cs);
  return image.updateMask(c);
};

var composite_free = sr.map(maskClouds).mean().clip(mumbai);
print(sr);
print(composite_free);

Map.addLayer(composite_free,visParams, 'composite collection without clouds');
```

I'm following the answers to these two questions, [Cloud mask for Landsat8 on Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277059/cloud-mask-for-landsat8-on-google-earth-engine) and [Cloud mask in Surface Reflectance Landsat 8 test](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271322/cloud-mask-in-surface-reflectance-landsat-8-test).

**My intended output from the script is to get a mean cloud-free image for the entire year.** But the `composite_free` image i.e. the mean image contains clouds (bellow image).

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Why this is the case? How to get the intended result? Also is there any inbuilt function of GEE which does the cloud masking?**

[My GEE code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/060bdf5e03b81e4715a8ec4b49841da5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bits are wrong; you're using 3 and 5, when it should be 3 and 4.
From the Landsat 8 Collection 2 (C2) Level 2 Science Product (L2SP) Guide (https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-8-collection-2-level-2-science-product-guide):

| Bit | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Fill |
| 1 | Dilated Cloud |
| 2 | Cirrus |
| 3 | Cloud |
| 4 | Cloud Shadow |
| 5 | Snow |