# Cloud mask error: Pattern 'cfmask' did not match any bands

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to "replace" the values of the cloud pixels for: it could be a mean, to calculate pre and pos-date NDVI for one country. 
I've used the code of a previous answer:
[Mask clouds in LandSat 8 surface refletance image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241822/mask-clouds-in-landsat-8-surface-refletance-image)

But this is giving error:

```js
ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=LC08_202033_20170804):
Image.select: Pattern 'cfmask' did not match any bands.
```

What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```js
//Choose country using GEE Feature Collection

var region = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw').filterMetadata('Country', 'equals', 'Portugal');

//Add region outline to layer ‐ for selected countries

Map.addLayer(region,{}, 'Portugal');


// image collection pre 11/10/2017

var lt8_pre = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(region) 
  .filterDate(ee.Date("2017-08-01"),ee.Date("2017-10-11")); 

var lt8_ndvi_pre = lt8_pre
  .map(function(img){  
  return img.addBands(img.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B5'])).updateMask(img.select(['cfmask']).neq(4));
  });

print(lt8_ndvi_pre);

Map.centerObject(region, 10);
var ndvi_viz = {min:-0.8, max:0.3, palette:'000000,00FF00'};
Map.addLayer(lt8_ndvi_pre.select('nd').mean(), ndvi_viz, "LT8 2017 NDVI mean pre 11/10");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your dataset description, there is not a cfmask in the selected collection, see: [Google Earth Engine Datasets Metadata](https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#detail/LANDSAT%2FLC08%2FC01%2FT1_SR)

In order to solve the issue you could change to a collection with cfmask or use the BQA band for filtering clouds.

Comment: Yes that's what they say but the USGS Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance metadata says: These data have been atmospherically corrected using LaSRC, and includes a cloud, shadow, water and snow mask produced using CFMASK, as well as a per-pixel saturation mask.

Comment: Well done. If you want you could accept the answer.